# How to fail a consteval function?

Tags: c++, c++20, consteval

I have the following function:

```cpp
template <size_t TSize>
consteval size_t indexOf(SomeEnum someEnum,
                         const std::array<SomeEnum, TSize> &arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TSize; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == someEnum) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  // How to fail here?
  return SOME_DEFAULT_WRONG_VALUE;
}
```

The function should fail instead of returning a default value, but I can't throw an exception or call `assert`. I can add a `static_assert` to every call to the function (with a macro it will be less horrible), but I'd prefer a solution that works in the function. Is there a way to trigger a compilation failure in such a scenario?

Comment: Generally these kinds of functions don't fail if they can't find the data, they return an out of bounds marker (usually -1). It's perfectly valid to search for something that doesn't exist in your collection.

Comment: Why can't you throw an exception or use `assert`?

Comment: @chris `consteval`.

Comment: @chris: You can't use `assert` in a constant expression context.

Comment: You can still `throw` from a `constexpr`. I'm not familiar enough with `consteval` to be certain, but I believe you should be able to `throw` from them as well.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you *think* throwing is not allowed in `consteval` or if you have an external requirement that you not use `throw`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: You can *write* `throw` in a `constexpr` function. You cannot *execute* any `throw` statements in constant evaluation; that causes a compile error. `consteval` only forces any calls to the function to be constant expressions; it doesn't change how they operate. So the standard rules of `constexpr` apply.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Then why can't throwing be used in `consteval` to produce a hard error when that code path is executed?

Comment: @chris: It can. One of the answers mentions this.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Then what was wrong with my original comment?

Comment: @chris: I was only speaking of `assert`.

Comment: @NicolBolas But [assert](https://godbolt.org/z/M13s1P5o7) seems to work as well. If the element exists, it compiles fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas, (Sorry, I'm multitasking right now and slow to reply. I also probably confused your initial reply with the more general one following it.) According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), `assert` should work as intended, even in an executed code path, as of C++17. I actually thought it was since C++14, but I guess either works in a C++20 context. Standardwise, that blurb is in [\[assertions.assert\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/assertions.assert).

Comment: "If I add an exception it is thrown at runtime, though." Your function is `consteval`, it is not thrown at runtime.

Comment: Also please don't edit answers into questions.

Comment: @Barry - "Your function is consteval, it is not thrown at runtime." 
if you want, I can record a screen capture and show you that you're wrong. I assume that it means that the Apple Clang compiler isn't entirely compliant with the standard.

Comment: @Barry, I don't understand why you edited my additional information out of the answer - it contained info which might be relevant to future viewers, who will want to understand or confirm this erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might simply omit the `return`

```
template <size_t TSize>
consteval size_t indexOf(SomeEnum someEnum,
                         const std::array<SomeEnum, TSize> &arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TSize; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == someEnum) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Px8rdG83z) (clang warns though about that method).

Compiler would reject code reaching that path.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c74sejE9z)

`throw` exception seems cleaner:

```
template <size_t TSize>
consteval size_t indexOf(SomeEnum someEnum,
                         const std::array<SomeEnum, TSize> &arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TSize; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == someEnum) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  throw 42; // or more meaningful exception
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xGMqPPs3K)

Comment: I would put a comment there to let people know that it is intensional, or just `throw` a value.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I would have used `throw`, until I saw that gcc reject it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cPPcTEs6v).

Comment: Then GCC is not following C++20 correctly.

Answer (score 17):

> Is there a way to trigger a compilation failure in such a scenario?

If the goal is to trigger a compilation failure, then the easiest thing to do is to throw an exception. Doesn't matter what the exception is, since it won't actually be thrown, it's the act of throwing an exception that will trigger a compile error because throwing is not allowed at constant evaluation time:

```cpp
template <size_t TSize>
consteval size_t indexOf(SomeEnum someEnum,
                         const std::array<SomeEnum, TSize> &arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TSize; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == someEnum) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  throw "failed to find someEnum";
}
```

If you want to be more explicit, you can just have a non-`constexpr` function without a definition:

```cpp
void trigger_consteval_failure(char const*);

template <size_t TSize>
consteval size_t indexOf(SomeEnum someEnum,
                         const std::array<SomeEnum, TSize> &arr) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TSize; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == someEnum) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  trigger_consteval_failure("failed to find someEnum");
}
```

In both cases, if you're looking for a value that *is* in the array, invoking this function is a valid constant expression. But if the index is *not* found, then we end up doing something that's now allowed in constant expressions and that's a hard compile error regardless, as desired.

It'd be nice if we could produce a better stack trace in this case, but I don't think there's actually a way to do that.

Comment: gcc rejects the `throw` though :( [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cPPcTEs6v)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's a bug they fixed in [10.3](https://godbolt.org/z/7qT5K3WEf)

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid working with indices and instead use `std::find` which is `constexpr` now. If you want an index, you can just use pointer arithmetic subtraction from the `begin`ing of the array to compute the index.

However, if you can't do that, then just return `TSize`; it should act like the end iterator.

Comment: Its (almost) always best to answer the question as code attached in questions is usually just an example of the problem and a way to communicate the solution.