# Implementing a consteval assert that gracefully falls back to assert when not in a consteval context?

Tags: c++, static-assert

Related:

- [How to get a compile time error in constant evaluated expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610746/how-to-get-a-compile-time-error-in-constant-evaluated-expression)
- [Enable static checks for constant evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586930/enable-static-checks-for-constant-evaluation)
- [How to fail a consteval function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320438/how-to-fail-a-consteval-function)

I want to have an assert macro that when possible is a `static_assert`, but falls back to `assert` when `static_assert` isn't possible. My sense is that `std::is_constant_evaluated()` should help with this, by being intended to allow constexper execution to use a different implementation than runtime execution, but everything I've tried like that fails:

```
#define ASSERT0(cond) \
if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) { \
    static_assert((cond)); \
} else { \
    assert((cond)); \
}

#define ASSERT1(cond) \
if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated()) { \
    static_assert((cond)); \
} else { \
    assert((cond)); \
}

#define ASSERT2(cond) \
if consteval { \
    static_assert((cond)); \
} else { \
    assert((cond)); \
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KzWfxMdMd

Fundamentally, as @BoP points out, the challenge is: when a function is being evaluated in a constexpr context, its arguments still aren't integral constants (https://godbolt.org/z/co93nc59h).

I'm new to `std::is_constant_evaluated()`. Is there something I'm missing? Should it be able to be used to switch between `static_assert` and `assert`?

Comment: please also include the example of how it fails in the question

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())` will always be true, as `if constexpr` is a constant expression.  You always want to use the form `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())`

Comment: And if you *don't* use `if constexpr` , both parts of the if-else must always compile. Catch-22!

Comment: @BoP exactly. I updated the question a little. Fundamentally it surprises me that in a function being evaluated in a constexpr context, the locals aren't integral constant expressions. Even if it's `consteval int foo(int x)` which is very surprising to me: https://godbolt.org/z/n83YvM9vT

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with `consteval`, but a `constexpr` function can be used in a non-const runtime context. However, the `static_assert` must still be evaluated when compiling the function, not when executing the call. A somewhat similar problem is that `if constexpr (true) { ok(); } else { static_assert(false); } ` will trigger the assert, even though it can never be executed.